# How to get Application_End to run while debugging (or when stopping debugging)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express, visual-studio-debugging, application-end

I want to handle application shutdown gracefully when stopping debugging or stopping the IIS Express web site, but I cannot seem to get Application_End to run.

Answer (score 13):

If you're debugging using IIS Express, the Application_End function will execute if you right-click on the IIS Express icon on the tray, select the proper site from the context menu and stop it. This will end your debugging session in a way that does execute the Application_End method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a change in web.config and save.